# what wrong with NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c++, nsnumber

i wrote this code :

```
bs = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[mystring.text floatValue]];
NSLog(@"bs = %@",bs);
```

....

```
float x = [bs floatValue];
```

when the program want to excute the line above it crash why ?

the output :
bs = 2.8 which true 100%

Comment: That code looks ok as long as bs doesn't get autoreleased. More code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the time you assigned an NSNumber object to your ivar bs it was release by the runtime.  I am assuming where you created bs and where you try to assign it to x are in two different methods.  If that is the case, you need to tell the runtime you want to keep the ivar bs around for awhile:

```
[bs retain];
```

And if you do that, you need to tell the runtime you are done in the dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [bs release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Basically, if you didn't create an object with alloc, copy, mutableCopy, new  in the method name, then you don't own the object.

Comment: Awesome 100% working but i put [ bs retain ] in first method but why if i didn't put it  bs lose its data ?

Comment: When you used the class method +numberWithFloat to create your NSNumber, you don't own the object.  The object is set to autorelease.  If you use the instance method -initWithFloat then you owned the object because you had to use +alloc to create it.  All part of Cocoa memory management.

Answer (score 1):

the code snippet seems ok.
and I guess the reason is `bs` was released before fetching its float value.
the simplest way to `retain` `bs` is to change it to a property:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSNumber* bs;
```

and `release` it in `dealloc`